convolution of the fundamental solution with the homogeneous solution
I have a question about the convolution of the fundamental solution with the homogeneous  solution. Namely if the 2 are convoluble then the homogeneous  solution is necessarily zero?
Let $U$ and $E$ be the homogeneous  and fundamental solutions for the differential operator $L$
Meaning that $LE=δ_0$ and $LU=0$
Now assume that $U$ and $E$ are convoluble so that $U*E$ makes sense.
Appling $L$ to $U*E$ we get
$L(U*E)=LU*E=U*LE$ by  the basic property of convolution
$LU*E=0*E=0$ and $U*LE=U*δ_0=U$ because the Dirac delta is the neutral element for convolution
So $U=0$
